# How to instantiate child of base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to implement a dynamic/evolving graph in c++. I have defined a base `DynamicGraph` class which all dynamic graphs will inherit from. This class provides a `transition` function which defines how the graph in round `r` is modified for round `r+1` I want to define `AdaptiveGossipGraph` which is a child of `DynamicGraph`, and will override the `transition` function.

`DynamicGraph.hpp`:

```
class DynamicGraph {
    
    public:
    
        int n;
        Graph *g;
        
        DynamicGraph(int n, bool directed) {
            // create G_0 on n vertices with no edges.
            this->n = n;
            Graph g1(n, directed);
            this->g = &g1;
        }   
        
        /**
         * Defines the dynamic graphs transition function from round to round.
         */
        virtual void transition();
};
```

`AdpativeGossipGraph.hpp`:

```
class AdaptiveGossipGraph : public DynamicGraph {       

    public:

        AdaptiveGossipGraph(int n, bool directed) {
            // would be nice to just do
            // super(n, directed);
            // but can't do this in c++
        }

        virtual void transition() override {
            // Implementation
            ...
        }
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```
int main() {
    int n = 5000;
    AdaptiveGossipGraph agg(n, false);
    ...
}
```

In the main program function, I want to instantiate an `AdaptiveGossipGraph` object, but am not sure how to do this. I am also not sure that my constructor for `DynamicGraph` will correctly set the member `Graph *g` since doing `Graph g1(...)` creates the object but as soon as the local scope is exited, the object `g1` is destroyed. This means `DynamicGraph`'s `g` pointer will be pointing to a location which no longer stores `g1`. Is this a valid concern?

Comment: `Graph g1(n, directed);` here `g1` is an automatic variable (local variable of the function) and it is destroyed at the end of its scope. Use `std::unique_ptr<Graph>( std::make_unique<Graph>(n, directed) );`

Comment: Thank you @digito_evo. But would how would I instantiate the `AdaptiveGossipGraph` class from my main function and what would the `AdaptiveGossipGraph` constructor look like?

Comment: Calling the base class constructor from the derived constructor: `AdaptiveGossipGraph(int n, bool directed): DynamicGraph(n, directed) { ... }`. Also I don't see any need for your local `g1` instance within your constructor - you can use `new` here to assign `g`

Comment: You might want to read up on constructor initializer lists. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/constructor-member-initializer-lists/

Answer (score 0):

lets breakdown the question and answer them one by one.

#### How to initialize base class from derived class?

you can [construct using initializer-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) (similar to supper)

```cpp
class AdaptiveGossipGraph : public DynamicGraph {
    public:
        AdaptiveGossipGraph(int n, bool directed):DynamicGraph(n,directed){}
};
```

#### How to initialize object inside main function

```cpp
 int main (){
    int n=5000;
    
    AdaptiveGossipGraph agg_1 {n, false};
    // or
    AdaptiveGossipGraph agg_2 (n, false);
    // or
    AdaptiveGossipGraph agg_3 = AdaptiveGossipGraph(n, false);
    
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `AdaptiveGossipGraph agg(n, false);` is not illegal, `AdaptiveGossipGraph agg();` would be.

Comment: my bad @Odysseus Thanks for pointing that out will correct my answerer